# How to transform/update and store incoming JSON property by applying PatternReplaceFilterFactory in SOLR 7.1.0

Tags: solr

I am pretty new to SOLR and we have a requirement where I have to modify one of the JSON property value from incoming request to get updated and stored. Something like the below one.
e.g.
{
  "name":"Google,CA,94043"
}

When I add this JSON via add/update documents using SOLR admin. I want this name to be stored as just Google. So when I do a search(query) *.* from SOLR admin it should list name as Google not "Google,CA,94043"

I have added FieldType with PatternReplaceFilterFactory and referenced the same to name field. The result is not appearing with the updated one. But when I analyze field value (index/query) using the admin tool it has the values correctly. Not sure how to achieve this.

Let me know if anyone has steps on how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you post the details of the pattern that you are using in the ` PatternReplaceFilterFactory` ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean that the Analyze screen has the values correctly? Could you include in your question what  you see and why you think that is correct?

Comment: @HectorCorrea Here is my PatternReplaceFilter                                
             <fieldType name="trimLocation" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=",.*" replacement="" replace="all"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
 </fieldType>

Comment: @HectorCorrea Analysis tool that appears in Solr Admin between overview & Data import on left side navigation.